# asp.net Code problems after writing a PNG to disk - iTextSharp and PDFStamper

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, canvas, itext

I'm successfully drawing on a HTML5 canvas and saving the canvas to a PNG file on the server.  Then I'm stamping the PNG into a PDF using iTextsharp. 
All that works great but here's my problem.

My code shows the PNG to the screen, when I don't want it to display.
I then have to have the User press the Back button to see the PDF list.
Everything works fine when this occurs but I don't want the PNG.
However, if I turn off the content type code for PNG, so the PNG doesn't display, then the PDF list isn't populated with the last PDF generated AND the code reruns a second time on the previous Canvas signature.  This is worse than seeing the PNG and pressing the back button.

Setting "response.end" won't work in the code situation I have. For I have to populate a hidden form variable with the Base64 PNG code and run some jquery.

Can you please suggest something I can do to not display the PNG but show the screen with the updated List?  I'm using asp.net vb   I'm not proficient with asp.net but am learning.

```
' take the canvas signature and write it to the Build folder path as a PNG
' the txtPNG hidden form field has the png base64
Dim base64 As String = txtPNG.Text
base64 = base64.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "")
Dim bytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64)
Response.Buffer = True
Response.Clear()
Response.ClearContent()

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(strBuildFilePath & "\" & strFilenameToSave & ".png", bytes)
Response.ContentType = "image/png"
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)

'do not use Response.end() or code doesn't work to generate the PDF etc.
```

This is  part of the JQUERY I'm using to move the PNG / canvas image around:

```
        $(function() {
            $("#btnSaveASP").on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var canvas = document.getElementById('cnvSignatureSketch');
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
                //alert(imgData);
                $("#<%=imgASP.ClientID %>")
            .attr("src", imgData)
               $("#<%=txtPNG.ClientID %>")
            .attr("value", imgData)

                //now click another button, btnexport,  via jquery
                //so user doesn't need to click two buttons
                $("#<%=btnExport.ClientID %>").click();
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

A good old fashioned `Response.redirect` worked after the `WriteAllBytes`.